Algebraic degree of accuracy of a quadrature formula

Given points $\{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}$, in quadrature formula $$\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}dx \approx \sum_{k=1}^{n}{A_kf(x_k)}$$ prove that there exist coefficients $A_k$, $k = \overline{1, n}$, for which given formula has algebraic degree of accuracy of $n-1$. Can this formula have algebraic degree of accuracy of $2n$?

I've solved the first part. If we try to solve the system:
\begin{align*}
  f_1(x_1)A_1 + f_1(x_2)A_2 + ... + f_1(x_n)A_n &= \,\int_{a}^{b}{f_1(x)}dx \\ 
  f_2(x_1)A_1 + f_2(x_2)A_2 + ... + f_2(x_n)A_n &= \,\int_{a}^{b}{f_2(x)}dx \\ 
  \vdots\\
  f_n(x_1)A_1 + f_n(x_2)A_2 + ... + f_n(x_n)A_n &= \,\int_{a}^{b}{f_n(x)}dx
\end{align*}
and we take $f_i(x) = x^{i-1}$, $i = \overline{1, n}$, the system becomes:
\begin{align*}
  1A_1 + 1A_2 + ... + 1A_n &= \,\int_{a}^{b}{1}dx \\ 
  x_1A_1 + x_2A_2 + ... + x_nA_n &= \,\int_{a}^{b}{x}dx \\ 
  \vdots\\
  x_1^{n-1}A_1 + x_2^{n-1}A_2 + ... + x_n^{n-1}A_n &= \,\int_{a}^{b}{x^{n-1}}dx
\end{align*}
The matrix of this system is transposed Vandermonde matrix, so the determinant is nonzero and we have an unique solution that satisfies that $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}dx = \sum_{k=1}^{n}{A_kf(x_k)}$ for every polynomial $f$ that has a degree less than or equal to $n-1$.
I am struggling with the second part, I have no idea how to prove it. I know that it can happen that this quadrature formula has an algebraic degree of accuracy of more than $n-1$ (although we can only guarantee degree of accuracy of $n-1$), but I don't know what's so special about $2n$ and why can it never be achieved.

Just to clarify, you're asking whether it's possible to have a degree $2n$ polynomial $f$ such that there exists $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ satisfying the first equality? Or are you asking whether it's possible to have all degree $2n$ polynomials satisfy the first equality?

I m asking if there exists $A_1, A_2,...,A_n$ such that the equality is satisfied for every polynomial of degree less than or equal to $2n$. If equality holds for polynomials $1, x, x^{2},...x^{2n}$ it holds for every polynomial of degree less than or equal to $2n$.

Try $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)^2$. This polynomial has degree $2n$ and the obvious roots.

Probably I wasn't clear enough, sorry about that. I need to check if $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}dx =\sum_{k=1}^{n}{A_kf(x_k)}$ can hold for $f_i(x) = x^{i-1}$, $i = \overline{1, 2n+1}$.

If we don't consider the general case, and we are in some sense lucky with $x_k$ that we are given, we can construct a Gaussian quadrature and get the algebraic degree of accuracy of $2n-1$. But I still don't know can we ever achieve degree of accuracy of $2n-1$.

Late for edit, I don't know if we can achieve degree of accuracy of $2n$.
